# replacing object inside 2d nested NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nested, nsmutablearray, 2d, nsarray

I'm having problem with replacing objects inside NSMutableArray which is an object inside another NSMutableArray.

In the interface:

NSMutableArray *tiles;

In the implementation:

tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",nil],
     [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",nil],
     [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",nil],nil];

[[tiles ObjectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withobject:@"1"];

It does compile but with an error: "NSMutableArray may not respond to ObjectAtIndex:", on this line:
[[tiles ObjectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withobject:@"1"];

Obviously it does not work.

Is it just a syntax problem? Or is it something can't be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with objectAtIndex (with a lowercase o for object).